# Combining Variables in a Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble combining `RangeToPaste` which is `Range("M3:R")` and `x` which is `Range("A1").Value`.

```
Sub AutoFillProjection()

Sheets("Projection").Select
    x = Range("A1").Value
    y = Range("A2").Value
    Dim RangeToCopy As Range
    Dim RangeToPaste As Range
    
    Set RangeToCopy = Range("M2:R2")
    Set RangeToPaste = Range("M3:R")
   
    RangeToCopy.Select
    Selection.Copy
    
    RangeToPaste & x.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    RangeToPaste & x.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: `Set RangeToPaste = Range("M3:R" & x)`

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. Sorry for the trouble. :)